# Writing a Rust test which expects a segfault

Tags: unit-testing, rust, segmentation-fault

I'd like to write a test in Rust where the *expected* behaviour of the `#[test]` function is to segfault. Is this possible?

Comment: Rust compiler guarantees that you will not get segmentation fault unless you are writing an `unsafe` notated code. Could you please share the code that makes your program to get segmentation fault.

Comment: @AkinerAlkan I mean, I could share the code, but the whole point of the exercise is that I'm writing a test to illustrate some edge cases in a library which uses `unsafe` internally.

Comment: Yes, fork your program, and do your code that must segfault in the child. Then verify that it was killed.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios Thanks! Do you know of any way to distinguish a segfault from a panic in this way?

Comment: segfault imply undefined behavior, undefined behavior imply undefined behavior. What you ask is non sense. The only way should be to send yourself a segfault signal.

Comment: Furthermore, if you can detect the situation in order to guarantee a segfault (instead of random corrupted data), why not just panic? And if you can't, what does your test do?

Comment: @SebastianRedl I'm using this test to detect whether or not someone else's library is still broken for some edge cases. If it is, that's the behaviour I'm expecting, and buildling my code around. I'd like to *know* if this changes in the future, and hence want my test to fail once the library is no longer broken.

Comment: @wen but that a false assumption UB is UB

Comment: On some platforms, dereferencing a null pointer (for example) always triggers a segfault. The OP can rely on this.

Comment: @FrenchBoiethios: You are assuming that the optimizer did not transform the program in a strange way based on the assumption that since the pointer was derferenced it was not null.

Comment: @wen It might be a better use of your time to fork the library and fix the bug instead of writing this test. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd like to point out that the only sure way to segfault that I am aware of is to send the SIGSEGV signal to your own process, possibly using the "raise" function or a rust equivalent.

Dereferencing a pointer to unallocated memory or a null pointer doesn't actually guarantee segfault, though it will on most modern platforms.

The simplest way to check for a segfault is to fork your program (possibly using the [nix crate](https://docs.rs/nix/0.13.0/nix/unistd/fn.fork.html)). Once done, execute the function that should make you segfault on the child process, while the parent process waits.

After waiting a sufficient amount of time (any more than a few hundred milliseconds is overkill), check that the child thread is dead. To do that, simply kill it, and an error should be raised if it's already dead.

Comment: "Dereferencing [...] a null pointer doesn't actually guarantee segfault, though it will on most modern platforms" *if* the compiler actually generates an instruction to dereference a null pointer. But since dereferencing 0 is UB, the compiled code may never actually do that, regardless of what it *looks* like it should do

Answer (score 1):

The only correct way to test this is, in my opinion, pretty heavy. In the test, I would run a static analyser that can detect this possible undefined behavior, and verify that this very issue is still there.

I am not aware of a Rust crate that does a static analysis, though, so I guess that you would depend on an extern tool using the C ABI.